# Jsoup set-cookies order error

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

This question also an issue [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/139). It considered as "fixed" but isn't.

For example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SZJ3.png)

I was received {csn_sid=deleted, csn_data=deleted} after login. Then I can't do anything because that wrong cookie. 
Anyone have a solution for this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know why I get down votes?

Comment: Welcome to the wonder- and helpful world of SO! I was not down-voting, but I suppose it happened because you did not write the full problem in the question. Just referring to an external resource to point to the actual question is considered bad style. You should use external links only for references and to make things even more clear. But the text of the question here on SO should be self sufficient to understand your problem. Next time try to pack everything in a small text together with your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the excellent [apache httpClient library](https://hc.apache.org/) to get the html content you want. The library has an nice [CookieStore](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) implementation that even keeps track of the cookies of a session.

With Jsoup it is not possible to handle situations when a web server returns with two headers with same name but different values.

Comment: But I need a HTML parser. Can I use both? Or another HTML parser library which can handle this situation well?

Comment: sure! First you get the content with httpClient and then you pass the content as string to JSoup. I do it all the time.

Comment: You are welcome If you feel that my answer helped then don't forget to up-vote. If the answer solves your problem sufficiently, please consider accepting the answer to mark this question as solved.